# Can I build Postgres 15 binaries on Linux so that they work on any distribution?

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-15

Previously, binary files of Postgres 10 could be downloaded from the site and they worked on any Linux. I need to build binaries for Postgres 15 in the same way so that they work on any distributions.

```
cd /home/username/postgres-15/build_postgres
../configure --prefix=/home/username/postgres-15/install
make
make install
```

I tried to build in Ubuntu 16, but it doesn't work in Centos 7. I tried to build in Centos 7 and it worked for Ubuntu 16, but now it doesn't work in Ubuntu 22 (**error while loading shared libraries: libldap_r-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**).

Is it possible to make a universal assembly ?

Answer (score 2):

Building a "universal binary" is effectively impossible when there are shared libraries involved, because different distributions (and distribution versions) may have incompatible versions of the library (as you see with `libldap` in your question).

Your best option is creating a self contained package that includes both the binary and any necessary libraries. This will work in *many* cases.

The simplest solution is to run your service in a container, because this gives you complete control over the runtime environment visible to the service. I can `docker run -d -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret postgres:15` on CentOS 7, Fedora 38, Ubuntu 22, etc. If you choose this option, the work has already been done for you; you can just use the official `postgres` image.

---

Alternatives to containers would be something like [AppImage](https://appimage.org), a distribution format created to solve exactly the problem you've encountered. I've never developed an appimage myself, so I can't really comment on ease of use.

I would just use the official `postgres` container and be done with it.